# Slide HTML Table rows up and repeate

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, html-table

I found some cool code while working on a project. Its jquery that effects a html table. It basically makes the tbody scroll up so the row that was at the top goes to the bottom and the rest of the rows shift up. This is what I mean:

```
<tr><td>1a</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>1b</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>1c</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>1d</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
```

becomes:

```
<tr><td>1b</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>1c</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>1d</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>1a</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
```

Row 1a moves to the bottom. This is the jquery code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.infiniteScrollUp=function(){
    var self=this,kids=self.children()
    kids.slice(20).hide()
    setInterval(function(){
        kids.filter(':hidden').eq(0).fadeIn()
        kids.eq(0).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).appendTo(self)
            kids=self.children()
        })
    },5000)
    return this
}
$(function(){
    $('tbody').infiniteScrollUp()
})
</script>
```

This works fine. No problems. How ever when I tried to make it so it just slides up, just like a reel of some sort, it either 1) stops adding it to the bottom, 2) stops removing them from the top, or 3) nothing. How can I change this effect to slide up?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YXcTp/) example.

Comment: The biggest problem is moving the table body without moving the table head. I've been looking around and I can find a way how to do that. If I could move the tbody without moving the thead it would be pretty easy to slide the tbody

Comment: In fact I haven't been able to apply any position styles to the tbody at all. They simply do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sliding tr elements up/down is tricky. They don't behave like block elements.

This is the best I can manage :

```
$.fn.infiniteScrollUp = function() {
    var self = this;
    var kids = self.children();
    kids.children('td, th').wrapInner('<div class="dummy"/>')
    setInterval(function() {
        var first = kids.eq(0),
            clone = first.clone().appendTo(self);
        first.find(".dummy").slideUp(1000, function() {
            kids = kids.not(first).add(clone);
            first.remove();
        });
    }, 2000);
    return this;
};
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pr4dH/1/)**

Comment: Thanks. I liked this one a lot more. Plus it does more of what I would like it do

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the plugin you have added above but here is another quick way around it that works as you have described, a little bit simpler in my opinion. There may be better ways around it.

```
function moveRows(){
   firstTR = $('tbody tr').first();
    firstTR.animate({opacity:0},
      function(){$('tbody').append(firstTR);});
    firstTR.animate({opacity:1});
}

setInterval(function(){
    moveRows();
},1000);
```

And here is a [Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/YXcTp/3/)